# ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream: Errors reading/Writing an appending Objects

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm appending Object with that code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ClaseAppendObjectStream extends ObjectOutputStream 
{
     public ClaseAppendObjectStream(OutputStream os) throws IOException 
     {
        super(os);
     }

     protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException 
     {  
         reset();
     }

 }
```

And that writes it on my file correctly with writeObject methos, but when i use the "readObject()" with the "objectinputStream".

More information:
     I've used "readObjectOverride"(using a subclass) and it has give me the same error.

It appeared that error:

"invalid stream header: 79757200."

I solucionated this error BUT it read the ".dat" file incorrectly.

My file .dat had 4 rows but i only read 1 row.  My code for reading is that:

```
ObjectInputStream objetoInStr = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(sPath))
{
    protected void readStreamHeader() throws IOException 
    {
    }
};

ClassEmployer[] getData = (ClassEmployer[])objetoInStr.readObject();

objetoInStr.close();
String sPhrase="";                      
for(ClassEmployer e : getData )
{
   sPhrase=sPhrase+"Name: " + e.getName() + " Salary: "+ e.getSalary();
}   
objTPane.setText(sPhrase);
```

It only shows me the last row.

I write my rows like that:

```
ClassEmployer[] employers= new ClassEmployer[1];
employers[0]= new ClassEm,ployer(objctotext1.getText().trim(),objecttext2.getText().trim());

FileOutputStream objetoFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(sPath,true);
BufferedOutputStream objetooutputBuffer = new BufferedOutputStream(objetoFileOutputStream);

ClaseAppendObjectStream objetoOutStr = new ClaseAppendObjectStream(objetooutputBuffer);
objetoOutStr.writeObject(employers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my owm misunderstanding. I' am reader other ask and answers of stack overflow.

First i had written my file correctly with AppendClass:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;

 public class ClaseAppendObjectStream extends ObjectOutputStream 
 {
      public ClaseAppendObjectStream(OutputStream os) throws IOException 
      {
          super(os);
      }

     protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException 
     {  
          reset();
     } 

 }
```

Read my file like that:

```
ObjectInputStream objetoInStr   = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(sPath))
{
    protected void readStreamHeader() throws IOException 
    {
    }
};
```

And finally read my object like that:

```
ClassEmployer Employer;                     

String sText="";
try
{       
    //Infinit reading
    while(true)
    {
        //that code wil have crashed with an EOFEXception
        Employer = (ClasseEmployer)objetoInStr.readObject();
        sText=sText+"Name: " + Employer.getName() + " Salary: "+ Employer.getSalary() +"\n";
    }   
}
catch(EOFException ex)
{
    objetotextoGrande.setText(sText);
}
```

And all of that id the solution. I'll hope helps other programmers like me.